# to Avoid catching similar folder names

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I'm doing a bash script and it needs to be generated first a text file with the paths that it will run the script. However, there are some paths that are similar in name and the grep command does not work properly to me.

The command used is:

```
find /base/path/ -type d | grep -i "$1" | grep -i ".root" | grep  -i "Inv" | grep -v "deleted"
```

This is my current ouput:

```
/base/path/lbasaur/Inv/DATA18/WenuL/group.phys-hdbs.mc16_13TeV.root
/base/path/lbasaur/Inv/DATA18/WenuL/group.phys-hdbs.mc16_13TeV_1.root
/base/path/lbasaur/InvCR/DATA16/Wenu/group.phys-hdbs.mc16_13TeV.root
/base/path/lbasaur/InvCR/DATA16/Wenu/group.phys-hdbs.mc16_13TeV_1.root
/base/path/lbasaur/InvCR/DATA16/WenuB/group.phys-hdbs.mc16_13TeV_2.root
/base/path/lbasaur/InvCR/DATA16/WenuB/group.phys-hdbs.mc16_13TeV_3.root
/base/path/lbasaur/InvCR/DATA16/WenuB/group.phys-hdbs.mc16_13TeV_4.root
```

but i only want the paths with 'Inv', not 'InvCR'. So, the names Inv and InvCR are pick up when i use this large command. How can i fix it?

Comment: Why are you piping to `grep` instead of just using the `-iname` or `-ipath` arguments to `find` to filter by name?

Comment: Can you show examples of the directory contents along with the files you want to match and the ones that should be excluded?

Comment: `.` in a regexp matches any character. If you want to match `.root` literally, use `grep -F`

Comment: some example could be:

base/path/large/path/of/content/word1/extra/content/
base/path/large/path/of/content/word1word2/extra/content/

if i use the command up there, they catch me the two paths, but i only want the first one.

Comment: I don't see `.root` or `inv` in either of them. Why should they be matched? Please add clarifications by editing the question, not in comments.

Comment: As you know the usage of `-v` option, you shoud know how to exclude the lines with `InvCR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see what you are getting at. There is a couple ways to exclude some name from a search you are using one already `grep -v "deleted"`

Using this same format we can exclude `InvCR`:

```
find /base/path/ -type d | grep -v 'InvCR'
```

You can use `-prune` as well:

```
find /base/path/ -path '*InvCR*' -prune -o -type d -print
```

Realistically you only need to use one `find` and a `grep` to accomplish what you want:

```
find /base/path/ -path '*deleted*' -prune -o -path '*InvCR*' -prune -o -type d -wholename '*Inv*' -print | grep -P '.*'"$1"'.*[.]root'
```

Note this is case sensitive to conform with your original code.